# Reference request: a cousin to the log semiring

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids, semirings

Let $f$ be strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $x \oplus y := f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))$ gives rise to a strict symmetric monoidal ($\Rightarrow$ commutative monoid) structure on $(\mathbb{R},\ge)$ with monoidal unit $f^{-1}(0)$. If $f(x) := \exp(x/h)$ for $h > 0$, then $([-\infty,\infty],\oplus,-\infty,+,0)$ is "the" widely used [log semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_semiring).

If $f(x) := \sigma(x)|x|^p$ for $p > 0$, then $(\mathbb{R},\oplus,0,\cdot,1)$ is also a semiring.

> This semiring does not appear to be widely used, and it is not
> well-known to me. What is it called, and where can I find references
> to it in the literature?

NB. I imagine that both of these semirings are morally unified under the aegis of "associated homogeneity" in the sense of Gel'fand and Shilov, i.e., with $\log$ a variant of homogeneous of degree zero.

Comment: What is $\sigma(x)$?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam It's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: It would be better to edit a definition of $\sigma(x)$ into the body of the question, than to make users chase it down offsite.

Comment: I'm confused about this question: it seems to me that, yes, this semiring, which is in fact a ring, is very widely used since it is simply (isomorphic to) the ring $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual addition and multiplication, the bijection $f$ being the isomorphism. Obviously for any mathematical structure $X$ and bijection $f$ from a different set $Y$ we can transfer the structure on $X$ to $Y$, but it's still the same structure! Now maybe there's still some reason to distinguish two isomorphic structures, but if so, it should have been clarified in the question.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Along with the exponential, this particular choice of $f$ is relevant for certain applications and actual numerical computations will be nice. A hint of this is on page 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05178. If you have seen this particular choice of $f$ used I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the OP, but is too long for a comment.

You may want to check Example (1.23) in J.S. Golan's *Semirings and their Applications* (Springer, 1999). The first sentence reads as follows:

> If $(R, +, \cdot\,)$ is a semiring and $X$ is a set together with a bijective function $\delta \colon X \to R$, then the semiring structure on $R$ induces a semiring structure $(X, \oplus, \odot)$ on $X$ with the operations defined by $x \oplus y = \delta^{-1}(\delta(x) + \delta(y))$ and $x \odot y = \delta^{-1}(\delta(x) \cdot \delta(y))$.

Golan mentions that a special case of this construction is considered by A.A. Mullin in: *On the algebraic structure of pre-rings*, Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 22 (1975), A703.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=%22pre-rings%22+mullin&btnG= shows nothing at all.

Comment: I haven't seen Mullin's paper, but it's almost surely an "extended abstract". The 1975 volume of the Notices is freely available: https://www.ams.org/cgi-bin/notices/amsnotices.pl?thispage=collectionnav&article_id=fullissue&article_type=gallery&gallery_type=fullissue&gallery_volume=1975 (unfortunately, Golan only gives the volume number).

Comment: It's on p. 47 of the November issue, and about the continued fraction stuff that Golan mentions.